# icon positioning off in iPhone 5+, fine on desktop and other mobile devices

Tags: ios, css, iphone, mobile, position

I have an icon that is attached to the :before of a span, as such:

```
<div class="user">
    <a href="/Account/SignIn?returnUrl=%2FSearch%3FcategoryId%3DAll%2BProducts%26criteria%3Dbike">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
    </a>
</div>

span.fa-user:before {
  color: #40bf40;
  font-size: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: -7px;
}
.fa-user:before {
  content: "\f007";
}
.top-bar .user {
  float: right;
  background-color: #3f4651;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 55px;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 40px;
}
nav ul:not(.side-nav) li a {
  padding: 0 16px;
}
```

This is how it looks in desktop and Android (the green user icon):

[image]

but on the iPhone, the icon is positioned wrong:

[image]

Why would the positioning be wrong just on the iPhone?

EDIT: I added the surrounding HTML and the styles and css

Comment: Can you show the code (html and css) that provides the gray background? My gut feeling says that there are some sizes in other units than pixels.

Comment: I edited the question to include the HTML around it. It was using "padding: 0 1em" on the <a> but I changed it to 16px and that didn't fix the problem.